# Imagenes usadas en seudolementos css ¿Es posible cambiar su tamaño?

Tags: css, css3

Muy buenas a todos. Respondiendo una pregunta de la comunidad se me vino otra duda, siempre que usó imágenes en pseudoelementos **::before** y **::after** las coloco como background porque siempre que las intento usar como contenido:

```
::before{
  content: url('imagen.jpg')
}
```

**A estas imágenes nunca les he podido modificar las dimensiones (alto y ancho)**, aunque el contenedor seudo si los tenga definido: **Ejemplo:**

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
}

div::before{
  content: url('http://lorempixel.com/120/120');
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  contenedor
</div>
```

**¿Es posible poder cambiar las dimensiones de esta imagen por css?** Sí es un sí **¿Que estoy haciendo mal?** y si no **¿Por qué, a qué se debe?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En respuesta corta, no se puede!

Puedes dar estilo a la caja generada por el pseudo elemeno `:before` pero no a la imagen generada a travez de `content`

Hay discuciones acerca de este caso en esta web, pero no un conseso de momento:

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/thread.html#msg451

Una manera de llevar a cabo lo que solicitas es utilizando `transform:` o `zoom` pero a este punto debes tener noción total del tamaño de la imagenes que estas insertando y del tamaño de la caja generada por `:before`

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
}

div::before{
  content: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100');
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  contenedor
</div>
```

Comment: No sabía sobre eso y tu respuesta hasta el momento es la más acertada. Muchas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las soluciones para corregir el tamaño de la imagen que deseas podría ser declarar el `content` como vacío y la imagen añadirla como un `background`, te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
}

div::before{
  content: '';
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/120/120');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  contenedor
</div>
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la respuesta, pero **si te fijas al comienzo precisamente explico que eso es lo que siempre hago**, porque de la otra forma no me funciona, quisiera saber porque no funciona del otro modo o si se puede, como sería.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez oh entonces no leí con detenimiento tu pregunta puesto que no vi que habías dicho eso, pido disculpas, yo siempre que uso imgs en estos casos lo hago como background, tampoco se como cambiar el tamaño del content

Comment: Si te entiendo, no te preocupes, al menos sé que no era solo yo quien lo hace así.